# What do study down and study up mean?

Tags: sociolinguistics

What do "study down" and "study up" mean?

They deem to be methods in sociologial or ethnographic researches:

> Regardless of whether you are ‘studying up’ or ‘studying down’, it is
>   crucial to think through the ethical implications of your findings.

[Researching the City: A Guide for Students](https://books.google.com/books?id=pUe3DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT86&lpg=PT86&dq=%22Regardless+of+whether+you+are+%E2%80%98studying+up%E2%80%99+or+%E2%80%98studying+down%E2%80%99,+it+is+crucial+to+think+through+the+ethical+implications+of+your+findings.%22&source=bl&ots=gq3BKGOm1o&sig=ACfU3U3duamqymLB92nkJtrN3lJavtA0bQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjV6YiL6fznAhVxHzQIHcuGCkcQ6AEwAXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Regardless%20of%20whether%20you%20are%20%E2%80%98studying%20up%E2%80%99%20or%20%E2%80%98studying%20down%E2%80%99%2C%20it%20is%20crucial%20to%20think%20through%20the%20ethical%20implications%20of%20your%20findings.%22&f=false)

Comment: What is the source of this quote?

Comment: My guess would be that this refers to using a "top-down" or "bottom-up" analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means studying groups who are above you (studying up) or below you (studying down) in power structures in society. [Here is an article from Ethnography Matters](http://ethnographymatters.net/blog/2014/03/10/studying-up/#:~:text=In%20anthropology%2C%20this%20kind%20of,power%20studied%20those%20without%20it.) which mentions the distinction. E.g. if you're a white middle-class cis heterosexual person then studying ethnic minorities, gay subcultures, or the very poor might be "studying down", while an immigrant/ethnic minority person studying rich white people might be "studying up".

It's also fairly obvious from context as immediately before, the OP's article is referring to the study of marginalised groups by people who may be less marginalised (and vice versa), and is discussing the ethical implications of studying those who are in a class above or below yourself.

It corresponds with similar phrases such as ["punching up" vs "punching down"](https://goodmenproject.com/featured-content/punching-up-punching-down-phtz/), which refers to making jokes about people who are socially/politically above you vs below you.